# An example of a finite $p$-group with cyclic and central Frattini subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, frattini-subgroup

Lemma 2.4 from Robert Griess' paper "Elementary abelian $p$-subgroups of algebraic groups".

(i) Let $T$ be a finite $p$-group whose Frattini subgroup is cyclic and central. Then $T'$ has order $1$ or $p$ and there are subgroups $X, Y$ such that $T$ = $X\circ Y$ where $X$ is extraspecial and $Y$ has an abelian maximal subgroup and $\Omega_1(Y)$ is elementary abelian.

(ii) If $T/T'$ is elementary abelian, $Y$ is of the form $p^r$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \times p^r$.

I've spent some time now on thinking of one example of $T$ such that its $Y $ is of the form $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \times p^r$. For $T$ the $Y$ of which of the former form, we have the extraspecial groups as examples, I suppose.

Comment: What does "$Y$ is of the form $p^r$" mean? Does that mean elementary abelian? And what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Yes sir. It means elementary abelian.  I am asking for an example of $T$ = $X\circ Y$ such that Y is of the second form, if I am not being stupid here...  Thank you!

Comment: For T with Y of the first form, extraspecial groups are examples, I suppose.

Comment: The smallest example is $X$ trivial and $T=Y$ cyclic of order $4$. If you want $X$ to be nontrivial, take a central product of the dihedral or quaternion group of order $8$ with $C_4$. They give rise to isomorphic groups of order $16$.

Comment: Yes sir. This makes sense. I am thinking: does it have to be $p^2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \times p^r$.  Can it be any power? Say a central product of quaternion with $C_8$? Because in the proof, this part is not really clear to me.  I appreciate the examples!

Comment: Please stop calling me "sir".